# Ubuntu 18 Apache .htaccess rewrite with wildcard to other directory - Beautify URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, apache2

Is it possible to create a rewrite code that includes a wildcard?

For example any request for:

```
https://eazita.com/live/*.m3u8
```

Rewrite to below directory

```
public_html/live/*/index.m3u8
```

The below htaccess file without wildcard is working fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^live/sda425sdf\.m3u8$ live/sda425sdf/index.m3u8 [NC]
```

But I want this with wildcard: (Something like this but this one is not working):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)\.m3u8$ live/$1/index.m3u8 [NC]
```

The apache error log says this:

```
[Thu Jan 09 17:56:27.459722 2020] [core:error] [pid 10264] [client 196.62.94.79:55537] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Can you provide examples without using `*` in URLs

Comment: http://eazita.com/live/5e16fdf3049d9.m3u8 they are just random alphabets with numbers. I tried this but no success.  RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^live/(.*)\.m3u8$ live/$1/index.m3u8 [NC]

Comment: So `http://eazita.com/live/5e16fdf3049d9.m3u8/` points to a directory with `index.m3u8` file in it?

Comment: Yes it should point to that random alphanumeric directory which has index.m3u8 file

Comment: ok can you post your existing .htaccess in question

Comment: Hi again, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/live/$1/index.m3u8 -f
RewriteRule ^live/([\w-]+)\.m3u8$ live/$1/index.m3u8 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice answer sir. Here is my understanding of it. 1- why you used `DOCUMENT_ROOT` because we need to use path further than root directory else we would have used REQUEST_FILENAME. 2- though `(.....)` to store matched regex is used in RewriteRule but we can use it in RewriteCond too. 3- then finally we are checking file's presence condition since OP is keep getting 500 internal errors because of no condition mentioned in his/her post. Could you please do let me know sir if my understanding is good here? Thank you for sharing good answers of htaccess they are really helpful.

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is needed here because we need to form full path to `index.m3u8` file to check its presence. On the other hand `REQUEST_FILENAME` is attempted full path from `REQUEST_URI`.